# Sending file on separate connection

Tags: unix-socket

I have a server program that spawns a thread for every incoming connection. This thread then handles the request by receiving it and sending a response. For some kinds of connections I have to respond first with a file and then with a text response.

The problem is that, if I send the textual response after sending the file, the response gets written inside the file, because the client has no way of knowing where the file ends and where the response beings. So I need to close the connection after sending the file and then send a response on other connection or, alternatively, send the file on a separate connection and then send the response on the current connection. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why don't you look at how HTTP handles it? It either sends the length first in the `Content-Length:` header, or it uses _chunked_ encoding, where it sends the response in pieces that are preceded by their length, using a block of length 0 to indicate the end.

Comment: That would greatly complicate the design, I want to use a separate connection FTP-style but I don't know how to properly create and use a second concurrent connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the technique that FTP uses to keep the data connection separate from the control connection. The server starts listening on an ephemeral port -- the OS will assign an unused port to it. It sends this port number to the client on the main connection. The client then connects to the ephemeral port, and the server sends the file on this new connection.

If you need to deal with multiple sockets concurrently, you can use `select()` or `epoll()` to wait for data on either of them.